# Apache2 Node Express unable to verify the first certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, apache2, swagger-node-express

What I am trying to do is to make an api endpoints using Node Express and Swagger.
The server that I am going to deploy the project is Ubuntu.

After I set up the node project on the server, installing Apache2 and set HTTPS with SSL certificates and key, accessing to the site worked well.

However, whenever I try to send API request from local to the server, it returns an error with "unable to verify the first certificate" message.

**The certificates and key files that I have are:**

1. CA_GLOBALSIGN_ROOT_CA.crt
2. File_Wildcard.servername.com.crt
3. ChainFile_ChainBundle.crt
4. KeyFile_Wildcard.servername.com_crt.key
5. complete_chain.crt (this is the one that I made through combining (1). (2), and (3) files).

**.conf file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName servername.com
    Redirect permanent / https://servername.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName servername.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/KeyFile_Wildcard.servername.com_crt.key
    SSLProxyCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/CA_GLOBALSIGN_ROOT_CA.crt
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/complete_chain.crt

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://servername.com:3005/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://servername.com:3005/
</VirtualHost>
```

**app.js file in node project:**

```
const express = require('express');
const orderRoutes = require('./routes/orderRoutes');
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');
const swaggerDef = require('./utils/swaggerDef');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const options = {
  swaggerDefinition: swaggerDef,
  apis: ['./routes/*.js', './controllers/*.js'],
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
app.use('/api', orderRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3005;

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/KeyFile_Wildcard.servername_crt.key');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync('/etc/apache2/ssl/complete_chain.crt');

const credentials = {
        key: privateKey,
        cert: certificate
}

const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

I did test openssl s_client -connect servername.com:443, but it also returns unable to verify the first certificate.

I also tried using nginx, but it resulted the same.

Could someone please help me solving out this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is contained in the chain? To setup the server (without client authentication) you'd *only* need the chain & the key file.

The *first* certificate expected by the client is the one of the server, followed by any intermediate certificates and then *optionally* followed by the root certificate. The client should already have the root certificate in their trust store after all.